# Lock CameraControl to X-Axis (Sideways) - SceneKit

Tags: swift, camera, scenekit

I have a sample sceneView containing a cube that continuously rotates around the x-axis. Now, I do want to allow camera control but I want the user to only be able to turn it sideways, on the x-axis.

I did not find anything on that topic. Is there a way of doing what I am aiming at?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: 3D objects (and cameras) are best thought of as having 3 types of  rotation: pitch, yaw and roll. I am a little limited in programming, but do understand 3D and cameras reasonably well, so if you can use these terms, I might be able to help you (a little)... here's a programmer describing this: https://sidvind.com/wiki/Yaw,_pitch,_roll_camera and this post clearly explains the limitations of this thinking with regards cameras and their subjects: http://www.openphotographyforums.com/forums/showthread.php?t=11652

Comment: Hey @Confused (great name btw :D). So I want to lock the rotation to the **yaw** (turning around the y-axis).